# SSL CA certificate details in hapi-mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl-certificate, hapi.js

Can't we have ssl certificate, keyfile, passphrase details specified in MONGO URI?

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1]][/[database][?cafile][&keyfile][&passphrase]]
```

Why I am asking this question is because I am using [hapi-mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-mongodb)

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Boom = require('boom');
 const launchServer = async function() {
    const dbOpts = {
        url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
        settings: {
            poolSize: 10
        },
        decorate: true
    };
    const server = Hapi.Server();
    await server.register({
        plugin: require('hapi-mongodb'),
        options: dbOpts
    });
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server started at ${server.info.uri}`);
};

launchServer().catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

**I cannot find how to add SSL Certificate details in `dbOpts` like `sslCA, sslKey, sslCert`? any help would be highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Marsup/hapi-mongodb/blob/7e9cd65/lib/index.js#L38 reads:

```
const db = await MongoClient.connect(connectionOptions.url, connectionOptions.settings);
```

And the second parameter of `MongoClient.connect` is documented at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/connecting/legacy-connection-settings/#individual-server-level-options

So your dbOpts must be something like

```
const dbOpts = {
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
    settings: {
        server: {
            poolSize: 10,
            sslKey:key,
            sslCert:cert
        }                
    },
    decorate: true
};
```

Comment: I add `settings: {
            poolSize: config.poolSize,
            sslKey: fs.readFileSync(key),
            sslCert: fs.readFileSync(cert),
            sslCA: fs.readFileSync(ca),
            sslPass: passPhrase
        }` and it worked. Thanks a ton Alex!!!!